# Show / Hide div depending on radio and checkbox buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this page: http://www.metagame.gg/champions/ I have several filters to display or hide the pictures below.

I have already created a script to show/hide the divs depending on the selection of radio buttons, but it only works when the 5 options are selected. Furthermore, I cannot figure out how to exclusively program the checkboxes.

The result of selecting different fields should be related by an **AND** condition.

In example: If I select Top and Tank and Melee, the displayed divs should be only the ones with the classes .top, .tank **and** .melee

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="selector">
<div id="selectorTitle">Champions filters</div>

<div id="selectorWrapperFirts">
    <div id="selectorSection">Position</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="posi" type="radio" value=".top" /> Top</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="posi" type="radio" value=".jungle" /> Jungle</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="posi" type="radio" value=".mid" /> Mid</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="posi" type="radio" value=".bot" /> Bot</label></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="selectorWrapper">
    <div id="selectorSection">Role</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="role" type="radio" value=".Assassin" /> Assassin</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="role" type="radio" value=".Fighter" /> Fighter</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="role" type="radio" value=".Marksman" /> Marksman</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="role" type="radio" value=".Mage" /> Mage</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="role" type="radio" value=".Support" /> Support</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="role" type="radio" value=".Tank" /> Tank</label></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="selectorWrapper">
    <div id="selectorSection">Damage Type</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="dmg" type="radio" value=".AD" /> AD</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="dmg" type="radio" value=".AP" /> AP</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="dmg" type="radio" value=".Hybrid" /> Hybrid</label></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="selectorWrapper">
    <div id="selectorSection">Power Spike</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="powers" type="radio" value=".egame" /> Early game</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="powers" type="radio" value=".mgame" /> Mid game</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="powers" type="radio" value=".lgame" /> Late game</label></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="selectorWrapper">
    <div id="selectorSection">Skill Ceiling</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="skill" type="radio" value=".Low" /> Low</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="skill" type="radio" value=".Normal" /> Normal</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="skill" type="radio" value=".High" /> High</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="skill" type="radio" value=".Vhigh" /> Very High</label></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="selectorWrapperLast">
    <div id="selectorSection">Qualities</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Ranged" /> Ranged</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Melee" /> Melee</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Crowd-Control" /> Crowd Control</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Engage" /> Engage</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Disengage" /> Disengage</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Counter-Engage" /> Counter engage</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Jungle-Clear" /> Jungle clear</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Burst" /> Burst</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Peel" /> Peel</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Poke" /> Poke</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Scape" /> Scape</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Siege" /> Siege</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Splitpush" /> Splitpush</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Sustain" /> Sustain</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Teamfight" /> Teamfight</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Wave-Clear" /> Wave clear</label></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="resetCheckboxesDiv">
    <button id="resetCheckboxes">Reset</button>
</div>
</div>
```

This is how the pictures HTML look. Notice the different classes that regulate the filters:

```
<div class="item  Melee Crowd-Control Engage  Counter-Engage Jungle-Clear Burst  Scape  Splitpush Sustain    Normal egame  Fighter    Tank Hybrid top jungle  ">
    <a href="aatrox">
        <img class="champavatar2" src="/icon/champions/aatrox.png" alt="">
        <div class="textavatar">Aatrox</div> 
    </a>
</div>

<div class="item Ranged  Crowd-Control Engage  Counter-Engage  Burst Poke Scape Siege  Sustain Teamfight Wave-Clear  High mgame Assassin   Mage   AP   mid ">
    <a href="ahri">
        <img class="champavatar2" src="/icon/champions/ahri.png" alt="">
        <div class="textavatar">Ahri</div> 
    </a>
</div>

<div class="item  Melee      Burst  Scape  Splitpush Sustain    Normal lgame Assassin Fighter     Hybrid top  mid ">
    <a href="akali">
        <img class="champavatar2" src="/icon/champions/akali.png" alt="">
        <div class="textavatar">Akali</div> 
    </a>
</div>

<div class="item  Melee Crowd-Control Engage Disengage Counter-Engage    Scape   Sustain Teamfight  Peel High lgame  Fighter   Support Tank AP    bot">
    <a href="alistar">
        <img class="champavatar2" src="/icon/champions/alistar.png" alt="">
        <div class="textavatar">Alistar</div> 
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is the JS that I managed to create. I insist that it only works when an option of each 5 radio buttons is selected.

```
    $('#selector input').click(function() {
        var position = $('input[name=posi]:checked').val();
        var role = $('input[name=role]:checked').val();
        var dmg = $('input[name=dmg]:checked').val();
        var powers = $('input[name=powers]:checked').val();
        var skill = $('input[name=skill]:checked').val();

        var selected = position + role + dmg + powers + skill;
        $('.item').not(selected).hide();
        $('.item' + selected).show();
    });
    $("#resetCheckboxes").click(function(){
        $("#selector input").removeAttr("checked");
        $('.item').show();
    })
```

I am a bit new to javascript so any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `.each()`

```
$('#selector input').on('change',function() {
     var selected = '';
     $('input:checked').each(function(){
        selected += $(this).val();
     });
     alert(selected);
     $('.item').not($(selected)).hide();
     $('.item' + selected).show();
 });
```

[**Demo Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/q3jazs5L/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't tryed and tested your code... I have to admit.
But as a first quick read of your js, I clearly see that you define vars based on their "checked" attribute. There is a hole when none is checked on a specific name input. The result is probably and "undefined" var. Did you checked the console results?

I'm sure it would be a great idea to set defaults values!

Something like this:

```
$('#selector input').click(function() {
    if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) ){
        // Your var definition
    }else{
        // Define a default value !
    }
}
```

Do this for each.

Comment: Thank you! that was the problem :) The console wasn't giving any error. Now I have to add the checkboxes :S

Comment: Try this for console log : console.log(position+" "+role+" "+dmg+" "+powers+" "+skill);

Answer (score 1):

You can check if any of the values is `undefined` or not and then proceed with the `show/hide` functionality.

```
$('#selector input').click(function() {
  var position = $('input[name=posi]:checked').val();
  var role = $('input[name=role]:checked').val();
  var dmg = $('input[name=dmg]:checked').val();
  var powers = $('input[name=powers]:checked').val();
  var skill = $('input[name=skill]:checked').val();
  if (position == undefined || role == undefined || dmg == undefined || powers == undefined || skill == undefined) {} else {
    var selected = position + role + dmg + powers + skill;
    console.log(selected, $('.item' + selected));
    $('.item').not(selected).hide();
    $('.item' + selected).show();
  }

});
```

Please refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wwxpk8c0/).